# When to use "pkill..." flag in newsyslog.conf?

Tags: openbsd, pkill

I'm configuring `relayd` to log to its own log, and I'm not clear on whether I should run `"pkill..."`.

I can see the following in the default `newsyslog.conf`:

```
# logfile_name      owner:group     mode count size when  flags
/var/log/maillog                    640  7     *    24    Z
/var/log/pflog                      600  3     250  *     ZB "pkill -HUP -u root -U root -t - -x pflogd"
/var/www/logs/access.log            644  4     *    $W0   Z "pkill -USR1 -u root -U root -x httpd"
/var/www/logs/error.log             644  7     250  *     Z "pkill -USR1 -u root -U root -x httpd"
```

I included the `maillog` line to show that there is no `"pkill..."` flags command for a log that is for a single daemon, which at least seems similar to my log configuration for `relayd`.

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate the log you are in fact creating a new file, which will be on a different inode.  Since `httpd` keeps its log file open while it's running, the file descriptor to which it writes the log messages will now point to a non-existing file.  This is why you need to send it the `SIGUSR1` signal, which will make it reopen the log file (i.e. drop the stale file descriptor and open the new file).  As per `httpd`'s [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/httpd).

> **httpd** rereads its configuration file when it receives `SIGHUP` and reopens log files when it receives `SIGUSR1`.

(Note that this is not an universal rule, `SIGUSR1` will trigger different things for different software.)

I am not entirely sure of this, but the fact that there is no need to signal `smtpd` that the log has been rotated strongly suggests that it keeps opening and closing the log file, which might be inexpensive on a mail server, but probably isn't on a busy HTTP server.

There is no indication of the need to signal `relayd` before rotating the log on its man page, but (and this is merely a hunch) I'd expect it to behave like `httpd`.  My instances of `relayd` use `syslog`, so I can't replicate your use case, but you can use something like `fstat | grep "relayd"` to check whether it keeps the log file open or not.

You'll get a more definitive answer asking on the `misc@openbsd.org` mailing list, or by [looking at the code](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.sbin/relayd/).

Comment: I ended up just experimenting, and although I can't explain why, the behavior is that `relayd` does not require a `reload`, as it happily pukes its handshake errors into the new file.